# Avenir Font Doesn't show up properly on Web Page opened on Any Browsers on Windows OS

Tags: html, css, windows, browser, fonts

I have used various **Avenir Fonts** on my website. It looks good on browser when opened in Linux, Mac, Ipad, Iphone, Andriod Phone. But when opened on any browser in Windows. Thus font doesn't look sharp and part of the text is not visible.

Below are two screenshot of how font renders on browsers in Windows OS:

**Windows Screenshot 1 :**

[image: Windows Screenshot 1]

**Windows Screenshot 2 :**

[image: Windows Screenshot 2]

Below are 2 screenshots showing how font renders on browser in Linux OS :

**Linux Screenshot 1 :**

[image: Linux screenshot 2]

**Linux Screenshot 2 :**

[image: Linux Screenshot 2]

Below is the code for **font-face CSS** for all font.

```
@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-Bold';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold/AvenirNext-Bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold/AvenirNext-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold/AvenirNext-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold/AvenirNext-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Bold/AvenirNext-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-BoldItalic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-BoldItalic/AvenirNext-BoldItalic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-BoldItalic/AvenirNext-BoldItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-BoldItalic/AvenirNext-BoldItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-BoldItalic/AvenirNext-BoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-BoldItalic/AvenirNext-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-DemiBold';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBold/AvenirNext-DemiBold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBold/AvenirNext-DemiBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBold/AvenirNext-DemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBold/AvenirNext-DemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBold/AvenirNext-DemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic/AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-Heavy';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Heavy/AvenirNext-Heavy.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Heavy/AvenirNext-Heavy.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Heavy/AvenirNext-Heavy.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Heavy/AvenirNext-Heavy.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Heavy/AvenirNext-Heavy.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-HeavyItalic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic/AvenirNext-HeavyItalic.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-Italic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Italic/AvenirNext-Italic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Italic/AvenirNext-Italic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Italic/AvenirNext-Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Italic/AvenirNext-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Italic/AvenirNext-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-Medium';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-MediumItalic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Medium/AvenirNext-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-UltraLight';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLight/AvenirNext-UltraLight.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLight/AvenirNext-UltraLight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLight/AvenirNext-UltraLight.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLight/AvenirNext-UltraLight.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLight/AvenirNext-UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype');} 

@font-face {font-family: 'AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic/AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

CSS assigned to the above description is as follow :

```
.description{
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "AvenirNext-DemiBold";
}
```

*Based on media query and device size the font size change from **13px to 22px***

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Checked on WIndows 8 and 10

Comment: I'm guessing there's no solution to this? Windows font rendering just sucks?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, where the font looked great on my Mac but didn't show up at all on a Windows device. It looks like the font just simply isn't licensed to be displayed on Windows devices. See more here: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-I-have-a-font-Avenir-on-my-Mac-but-not-on-my-PC-The-font-is-not-in-TypeKit-which-I-am-still-trying-o-figure-out-I-looked-online-and-its-250-to-350-Can-I-pop-it-into-Dropbox-and-add-it-to-my-PC-that-way

From that Quora answer: "The font family Avenir is licensed just like your operating system or your apps. Now, in this case, it is bundled with the operating system, so your macOS license also covers it. Monotype owns Avenir, and has licensed it to Apple, who have licensed it to you with macOS. That does not give you the right to copy it over to other computers that don’t have it bundled."

The solution I used was to replace Avenir with Montserrat, which looks very similar. Link to Montserrat on Fontsource: https://fontsource.org/fonts/montserrat

You can also find other alternatives to Avenir here: https://learnui.design/blog/avenir-similar-fonts.html